# Integral comparison test for $\frac{1}{x \ln(x)^2} $ or $\frac{1}{x \log(x)^2}$ on $(0, \frac{1}{2})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to show $f(x) = \frac{1}{x \ln(x)^2}$ on the interval $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ is in $L^p$ only for $p=1$ and not for $p>1$. I can show $||f||_{L^1( (0,\frac{1}{2}) )} < \infty $ but for $p>1$, I have a hard time figuring out how to evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{x^p \ln(x)^{2p}} dx$. Change of variable with $u= \ln(x)$ gives me $\int_{-\infty}^{\ln(\frac{1}{2})} \frac{1}{(e^u)^{p-1} u^{2p}} du$ which looks like I should try an integral test instead.

Comment: My understanding is that $\frac{1}{\log(x)} \geq \frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha}}$ only for $x \geq 1$ . The interval that I am integrating over is $(0, 0.5)$ so this will not work unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

For any $\alpha>0$, note that $\frac{x^\alpha -1}{\alpha x^\alpha}\le\log(x)$.  For $0<x<1$, this gives the inequalities

$$\frac1{\log^2(x)}\ge \frac{\alpha^2 x^{2\alpha}}{(x^\alpha -1)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, the inequality is true and it works, I would not have been able to come up with this function by myself.......

Answer (score 0):

For $p=1,$ the integral can be evaluated in closed form. For $p>1,$ your integral is greater than the integral of $1/x$ which diverges at $0$ (since $\log(x)^2$ grows slower than any power of $x$ at $0$).

Comment: How do I show that $\frac{1}{x}$ is less than the integral that I am looking at on $(0,0.5)$? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pjs8tv1tqt

Comment: I don't think this is a valid argument. If you evaluate the integral of $1/x$ it's the well known $\log x$, which tends to negative infinity if evaluated at $0$. So it's inconclusive.

Comment: @vitamind since when is being greater than infinity viewed as "inconclusive"?

Comment: @user770687 You only have to look at a small neighborhood of zero. Everything converges everywhere else.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\log x \to -\infty$

Comment: I am afraid the plots on are misleading me https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rm4e9g3odd Where exactly does $1/x$ start being smaller than $\frac{1}{x^p \log(x)^{2p}}$ may I ask?